# count and grouped by

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to count the number of records in the `car_number` field, grouped by `country`.

My models.py

```
class country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default="none")
    volgorde = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

class car(models.Model):
    car_number = models.CharField(verbose_name='VIN',max_length=11,unique=True,blank=False ,validators=[numeric])
    car_country = models.ForeignKey('country', verbose_name='Country',blank=True, null=True, default=1, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.car_number)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("car:list", kwargs={"id":self.id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-car_number"]
```

My views.py

```
class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  car.objects.only('car_country').select_related('car_country')
    serializer_class = CarSerializer


class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = country
    fields = ('country_name',)

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    car_country = CountrySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = car
        fields = ('car_number','car_country',)
```

The result I got now is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "car_number": "45678",
        "car_country": {
            "country_name": "Europe/UK"
        }
    },
    {
        "car_number": "3333333",
        "car_country": {
            "country_name": "Europe / Netherlands"
        }
    },
    {
        "car_number": "11111111111",
        "car_country": {
            "country_name": "Europe/UK"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: Hi Stevy, I added the models

Comment: Thank you. I am not really sure what your desired output is. What fields do you want to count exactly?

Comment: I modified my question. Results should be a list of countries (orderd by) with number of (count)  car_numbers.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your class names should start with a capital letter.

To return a list of countries with the amount of related `car_numbers` first add [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to your model like this:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    car_number = models.CharField(verbose_name='VIN',max_length=11,unique=True,blank=False ,validators=[numeric])
    car_country = models.ForeignKey('Country', verbose_name='Country',blank=True, null=True, default=1, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='cars')
```

Then you can use [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) and [`order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) in the query in your view like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  Country.objects.all().annotate(car_amount=Count('cars')).order_by('-car_amount')
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer
```

To get the right output, we use a [`SerializerMethodField()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to grab the count of `Car` objects for a specific `Country` like this:

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    count_cars = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_count_cars(model):
        return model.cars.all().count()

    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ('country_name' 'count_cars',)
```

Output should look like:

```
[
    {
        "country_name": "Europe/UK",
        "count_cars": 10
    },
    {
        "country_name": "Netherlands",
        "count_cars": 6
    },
    {
        "country_name": "Belgium",
        "count_cars": 3
    },
]
```

If you want the output to be ascending instead of descending, remove the `-` from your `order_by()`.

**Descending order, based on count of cars:**

`Country.objects.all().annotate(car_amount=Count('cars')).order_by('-car_amount')`

**Ascending order, based on count of cars:**

`Country.objects.all().annotate(car_amount=Count('cars')).order_by('car_amount')`